# Automate the Barcode Batch printing using batch programming

Tags: batch-file, serialization, printing, barcode

Hi I am trying to automate my serial barcode printing by using .bat files. My barcode contains a 13 digit number with 4 digits as constant from the left side (for example "WXYZ000000000" where WXYZ are constant and serialization is from 000000000 to 999999999). For this I have created a PRN file which is

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='25.1 mm'></xpml>SIZE 46.4 mm, 25.1 mm
GAP 3 mm, 0 mm
DIRECTION 0,0
REFERENCE 0,0
OFFSET 0 mm
SET TEAR OFF
SET CUTTER OFF
SET PARTIAL_CUTTER OFF
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='25.1 mm'></xpml>DOWNLOAD 
"FORM_0.BAS"
BARCODE 496,277,"128",204,0,180,3,6,AA$
CODEPAGE 1252
TEXT 377,65,"0",180,8,8,AB$
EOP
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='25.1 mm'>
</xpml>AA$="WXYZ000000000"
AB$="WXYZ000000000"
SIZE 46.4 mm, 25.1 mm
GAP 3 mm, 0 mm
SET PEEL ON
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml>KILL "FORM_0.BAS"
<xpml><end/></xpml>
```

Now all I need is to replace the 9 digit zeros with the user defined entry. ( Ex. 1000 serial labels from 000045785.

I have written a batch file but it seems to be printing the same barcode. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Barcode printing
ECHO From where to start printing:
SET /P Num1Add=
ECHO How much barcode you want from the first number:
SET /P Num2Add=
ECHO.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Num2Add%) DO (
powershell -Command "(gc 124.prn) -replace '000000000', '%Num1Add%' | Out File -encoding ASCII 125.prn"
COPY C:\125.PRN /B \\PC1\Printer
set /A Num1Add=!Num1Add!+1
echo !Num1Add!
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Num2Add%) DO (
 set "nextnum=000000000!num1add!"
 powershell -Command "(gc 124.prn) -replace '000000000', '!nextnum:~-9!' | Out File -encoding ASCII 125.prn"
 COPY C:\125.PRN /B \\PC1\Printer
 set /A Num1Add+=1
 echo !Num1Add!
)
```

Changes to your code, step-by-step:

1. The reason the same code is being generated is that you are using `%num1add%`. Please search SO for `delayed expansion`. `%num1add%` is replaced by its *initial* value; to get the run-time value (as it changes) you need `!num1add!`
2. You would have noticed that the `num1add` shown by the `echo` has the leading zeroes suppressed. Also possibly that the `echo` is of `!num1add!` ( the *run-time* value). Consequently, your code would have replaced `000000000` with `1234`, not `000001234`. The way around this is to append your number to `000000000` and then take the last 9 characters of the resultant string (`!nextnum:~-9!`) - note this is a substring of the *run-time* value of `nextnum`.
3. You possibly wouldn't have tripped over the next problem immediately - or maybe you disregarded it. When batch interprets a string which contains leading zeroes as a number, it assumes that since there are leading zeroes, the number is *octal*. Hence it would object to any `8` or `9` in the number, and would regard '00001234' as *668*, so the series would be 669, 670 etc. The `set /a` syntax uses the *run-time* variable value unless the argument is `%var%` for the reasons in `delayed expansion`. Hence the simpler code using `set /a` syntax to increment your value.

Personally, I'd re-think your numbering scheme, as 13-digit codes are used in commerce as article-id codes (as are 8-digit and 12-digit; 14-digit are codes for packages) so if there's any possibility that they may become confused, no doubt they will be.

Oh - and don't enter the leading zeroes. Leave that to batch.

Comment: Great ! It works, thanks for this useful info. Thumbs up mate.